# How to use BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE for User defined types

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, c++03

I want to check object of following types if they are **almost/close** to expected value.

```
class MyTypeWithDouble
{
    public:
      MyTypeWithDouble(double); 
      bool operator == (const MyTypeWithDouble& rhs) const; //Checks for Equality
    private:
      double m; 
};

/////////////////////////////////////////

class MyTypeWithVector
{
    public:
      MyTypeWithVector(std::vector<double>v);
      bool operator == (const MyTypeWithVector& rhs) const; //Checks for Equality 
    private:
      std::vector<double> v;
};
```

So that the unit test looks like this

```
/// TEST1 ////////////////
MyTypeWithDouble t1(42.100001);
BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(t1,42.1,0.1); 

//////TEST2//////////////////////////////


std::vector<double> v; //no initalizer do not have c++11 :-(
v.push_back(42.1); 
MyTypeWithVector t2(v);
std::vector<double> compare;
compare.push_back(42.100001);

MY_OWN_FUNCTION_USING_BOOST(t2,compare,0.1); //There is only   BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTION available for collections
```

- I do not want to change the implementation of of the '== operator's or
  provide Getters.
- Adding other operators functions is OK.

Thanks, ToBe

Comment: I am pretty sure you will need to overload the `<` and `>` operators to achieve this.

Comment: @Ben I'm pretty sure this is a bit of an understatement :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're overengineering this. I'd suggest a simple macro, perhaps with a suitable friend definition. That said, let's accept the challenge.

---

## Necessary adjustments

Your type should

- be default-constructible for the `check_is_close_t` implementation.
- also, there **must** be a way to get at the value, and since you refuse to create a getter, the only option left is to declare an accessor class as friend

We get

```
class MyTypeWithDouble
{
    public:
      constexpr MyTypeWithDouble(double v = 0) : m(v) {}
      MyTypeWithDouble& operator=(MyTypeWithDouble const&) noexcept = default;
      constexpr MyTypeWithDouble(MyTypeWithDouble const&) noexcept = default;
    private:
      friend class unittest_op::access;
      double m;
};
```

With a bit of tedious work (in a header?) we can use this `access` loophole to implement everything else. **How?** Well, we define a "getter", alright, but *outside the class definition*.

I defined a trait class template inside `access` (so it is implicitly a `friend`) and you can specialize for your "floating-point-like" type:

```
namespace unittest_op {
    template<> class access::impl<MyTypeWithDouble> {
      public:
        typedef double result_type;
        static result_type call(MyTypeWithDouble const& v) { return v.m; }
    };
}
```

**That's All**. Well, that's all for *you* as a type/test implementor. Of course, we still need to make this work.

---

## The Nuts And Bolts

The `unittest_op` namespace exists for the sole reason to define "relaying" operators that know how to access the contained value inside your custom type.

Note how we

- didn't need to add anything to your user-defined type
- we get mixed operands as well (e.g. `2 * MyTypeWithDouble(7.0) -> MyTypeWithDouble(14.0)`)
- and we also defined `operator<<` so the assert macros know how to print values of `MyTypeWithDouble`

Thanks to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) the work is not complicated:

```
namespace unittest_op {
    class access {
        template<typename T, typename Enable = void> class impl;

        template<typename T>
            class impl<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void>::type>
        {
          public: typedef T result_type;
            static T            & call(T& v) { return v; }
            static T const& call(T const& v) { return v; }
        };

      public:
        template<typename T>
        static typename impl<T>::result_type do_access(T const& v) { return impl<T>::call(v); }

        template<typename T> static constexpr bool can_access(decltype(do_access(std::declval<T>()))*) { return true; }
        template<typename T> static constexpr bool can_access(...) { return false; }
    };

    template<typename T>
        typename std::enable_if<access::can_access<T>(nullptr) && not std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::ostream&>::type
            operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const& v) { return os << "{" << access::do_access(v) << "}"; }

    template <typename T, typename Enable=decltype(access::do_access(std::declval<T>())) >
        static T operator-(T const& lhs) { return - access::do_access(lhs); }

    template <typename T, typename Enable=decltype(access::do_access(std::declval<T>())) >
        static T operator+(T const& lhs) { return + access::do_access(lhs); }

#define UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(OP) \
    template <typename T1, typename T2> \
        static decltype(access::do_access(std::declval<T1>()) OP access::do_access(std::declval<T2>()))  \
            operator OP(T1 const& lhs, T2 const& rhs) { return access::do_access(lhs) OP access::do_access(rhs); } \
    using ::unittest_op::operator OP;

    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(==)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(!=)

    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(< )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(> )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(<=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(>=)

    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(+ )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(- )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(% )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(* )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(/ )

    // assign-ops only for lvalue types (i.e. identity `access::impl<T>`)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(+=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(-=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(%=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(*=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(/=)

#undef UNITTEST_OP_BINOP
}
```

Note that these are all "open" templates, and we've taken the necessary precautions to make sure that these operators **only** apply iff `do_access` is defined **and** the type wasn't an arithmetic type to begin with.

**Why These Precautions?**

Well. We're going to do a power-move: We're going to inject our operator overloads into the `boost::test_tools` namespace, so that `BOOST_CHECK*` macro implementation can find them.

Had we *not* taken the precautions just mentioned, we would invite a lot of problems due to ambiguous operator overloads for types that we didn't care about.

---

## The Power Grab

The power grab is simple: we inject (`using`) each of our operator templates inside the `boost::test_tools` namespace.

Now we're good to go:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10c5c5de0fdfb867)</kbd>**

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test)
{
    MyTypeWithDouble v(4);

    BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(3.99, v, MyTypeWithDouble(0.1));
}
```

Prints

```
Running 2 test cases...
main.cpp(117): error in "my_test": difference{0.25%} between 3.99{3.9900000000000002} and v{{4}} exceeds {0.10000000000000001}%
```

---

## Full Program

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10c5c5de0fdfb867)</kbd>**

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace unittest_op {
    class access {
        template<typename T, typename Enable = void> class impl;

        template<typename T>
            class impl<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void>::type>
        {
          public: typedef T result_type;
            static T            & call(T& v) { return v; }
            static T const& call(T const& v) { return v; }
        };

      public:
        template<typename T>
        static typename impl<T>::result_type do_access(T const& v) { return impl<T>::call(v); }

        template<typename T> static constexpr bool can_access(decltype(do_access(std::declval<T>()))*) { return true; }
        template<typename T> static constexpr bool can_access(...) { return false; }
    };

    template<typename T>
        typename std::enable_if<access::can_access<T>(nullptr) && not std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::ostream&>::type
            operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const& v) { return os << "{" << access::do_access(v) << "}"; }

    template <typename T, typename Enable=decltype(access::do_access(std::declval<T>())) >
        static T operator-(T const& lhs) { return - access::do_access(lhs); }

    template <typename T, typename Enable=decltype(access::do_access(std::declval<T>())) >
        static T operator+(T const& lhs) { return + access::do_access(lhs); }

#define UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(OP) \
    template <typename T1, typename T2> \
        static decltype(access::do_access(std::declval<T1>()) OP access::do_access(std::declval<T2>()))  \
            operator OP(T1 const& lhs, T2 const& rhs) { return access::do_access(lhs) OP access::do_access(rhs); } \
    using ::unittest_op::operator OP;

    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(==)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(!=)

    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(< )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(> )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(<=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(>=)

    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(+ )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(- )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(% )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(* )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(/ )

    // assign-ops only for lvalue types (i.e. identity `access::impl<T>`)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(+=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(-=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(%=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(*=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(/=)

#undef UNITTEST_OP_BINOP
}

namespace boost { namespace test_tools {

    using unittest_op::operator ==;
    using unittest_op::operator !=;

    using unittest_op::operator < ;
    using unittest_op::operator > ;
    using unittest_op::operator <=;
    using unittest_op::operator >=;

    using unittest_op::operator + ;
    using unittest_op::operator - ;
    using unittest_op::operator % ;
    using unittest_op::operator * ;
    using unittest_op::operator / ;

    using unittest_op::operator +=;
    using unittest_op::operator -=;
    using unittest_op::operator %=;
    using unittest_op::operator *=;
    using unittest_op::operator /=;

    using unittest_op::operator <<;

} }

class MyTypeWithDouble
{
    public:
      constexpr MyTypeWithDouble(double v = 0) : m(v) {}
      MyTypeWithDouble& operator=(MyTypeWithDouble const&) noexcept = default;
      constexpr MyTypeWithDouble(MyTypeWithDouble const&) noexcept = default;
    private:
      friend class unittest_op::access;
      double m;
};

namespace unittest_op {
    template<> class access::impl<MyTypeWithDouble> {
      public:
        typedef double result_type;
        static result_type call(MyTypeWithDouble const& v) { return v.m; }
    };
}

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test)
{
    MyTypeWithDouble v(4);

    BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(3.99, v, MyTypeWithDouble(0.1));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(general_operator_invocations) // just a testbed to see the overloads are found and compile
{
    MyTypeWithDouble v(4);

    using namespace unittest_op; // we're not using the test_tools here

    BOOST_CHECK(4.00000000000000001 == v);
    BOOST_CHECK(4.000000000000001   != v);

#define UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(OP) { \
    auto x = v OP static_cast<MyTypeWithDouble>(0.01); \
    x = static_cast<MyTypeWithDouble>(0.01) OP v; \
    x = v OP v; \
    (void) x; \
}

    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(==)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(!=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(+ )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(- )
    //UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(% )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(* )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(/ )

    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(< )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(> )
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(<=)
    UNITTEST_OP_BINOP(>=)

    -v == -v;
    +v == +v;
}
```